# Solar for particular electronic equipment

Tags: home-automation, solar-panels, solar

I am living in a rental house. Earlier i had an idea to install solar panel for whole house but the cost is very high and other problem is if i am going to shift the house I want to move solar installation too.

Now i am thinking of using Solar panel for only one or two electronic items in the house.

Any experienced person can help me?

I am planning to do it my self.

Comment: Possible, but your question is too broad to answer it in this format.  To prepare, familiarize yourself with the power needs of each of the appliances in question (in watts), and find out of that appliance (or another you could buy) is able to work on 12 volts DC. For instance some TVs can accept 12VDC, others cannot.  It would also help to understand the core problem you are trying to solve and the context.

Comment: Yes. You are correct @Harper Lets say if i want to use solar panel for my refrigerator.

Comment: Refrigerators have large starting requirements not a good option for a portable solar on top of a fairly large array a charge controller batteries for storage and an inverter to run the fridge at night would all be needed.

Comment: look into small 12v starter (inverter-less) systems; you can get going for a hundred usd or two. A fridge is probably out of the question, but there's a lot of other uses for the solar power. Stop by a truck stop and peruse the selection of 12v appliances; you can get everything from coffeemakers to fans to lights and more.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts as you proceed:  It takes quite a few panels to make much electricity.  And second, don't fasten anything down.  If you do, it legally becomes apart of the real property.  It also takes a lot of batteries to store any significant amount of run time for even limited equipment. People who win with solar invest a lot of money upfront.  It can be a great hobby; one you can have a lot of fun with and learn a lot. Just be aware of its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Solar in a rental is unlikely to work well,

- Solar panels need to be hooked to the electrical equipment, which is difficult because they're outside and the equipment is inside.
- You either need a battery system (needs space and money) or you need to be ok with not having 100% uptime.
- The standard place to put residential panels is on the roof, which is a permanent installation. Other places interfere with your usage of the house.
- When you move out, if you want to use the panels, you'll be restricted in where you can move.

My recommendation is to examine your house's weatherstripping, and generally look for drafts. Rentals tend to have issues because the person paying for the work isn't the one paying the heating/cooling bill, but replacing weatherstripping is within DIY levels, and can pay for itself within a year.